# How do I retrieve inbound SMS phone number from twilio request in Python

Tags: python, django, twilio

I'm attempting to get the "from" number from an SMS message that I send to my Twilio number.

I have a Django server running that takes this message and performs some back-end processing, but I can't seem to retrieve the "from" number that sends that SMS to the Twilio number via Python. I keep getting 500 errors that state that this 'from' attribute doesn't exist but the Twilio [documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message) states otherwise.

```
def respond_to_sms(request):

# save the http request message
twilio_request = decompose(request)

# this works fine
twilio_message_body = twilio_request.body

# this does not
from_number = twilio_request.from

# perform backend stuff on from_number
```

Anyone know how to do this? I'm using the Django-Twilio package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You almost got it right, but it turns out that in the Python library, the name of the attribute is `from_` as opposed to just `from`. That's because in Python, `from` is a reserved keyword as you can see [here](https://docs.python.org/2.5/ref/keywords.html).

So try changing your code to the following:

```
from_number = twilio_request.from_
```

And you'll get it working. More information about the library can be found [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/python/install).

Hope this helps you out!